# asp.net mvc action method to receive model and additional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm still kinda fuzzy on mvc mapping to action methods but here's what I understand:

If the app does a form.submit on, say `http://mysite/mycontroller/myaction` , mvc will a) look for a method named myaction on mycontroller that receives a model as a parameter, and b) create an instance of the model and populate the properties whose names match the form fields.   and c) call that method passing that model as a parm.  Correct so far?

I want to pass an additional parameter on the url, e.g., my url will be

```
http://mysite/mycontroller/myaction/someparmvalue
```

and I hoped I could receive that parm by declaring my method as

```
public ActionResult Export(MyModel m, string someparm)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. The model instance is created, the method is called, but the someparm value is null.  Am I misunderstanding the way this should work?

Comment: Do you have a route setup that accepts `{someparmvalue}`?

Comment: That was it!  thanks.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to have `{someparmvalue}` defined in your route.